FlatList is calling the onEndReached function on the initial load and not calling it when reaching the end
In react native, FlatList is calling the onEndReached function on the initial load and not calling it when reaching the end of the list.
I tried doing everything, from changing the threshold to adding a container with flex: 1;. But it's not working :/
The problem is that, I have ScrollView in parent (ScrollView is nesting the FlatList). This is the main problem, I also tried setting nestedScrollEnabled. But still not working.
Here's my FlatList component:
<FlatList
  data={stationComments}
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item: comment }) =>
    <Review
      key={comment.commentId}
      comment={comment}
    />
  }
  onEndReached={() => nextPage()}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0}
/>

Thanks!

You need to somehow implement a mechanism so that onEndReached will be called only after initial data fetch is complete, not before that. Which will not call the onEndReached initially

The issue might be that the stationComments section on the first page has a list height less than the device screen height, which could trigger the next page call. Alternatively, it could be due to the length of stationComments.
The condition stationComments.length === 30 ensures nextPage is only called if there are exactly 30 items, implying a full page of data is loaded,
<FlatList
data={stationComments}
renderItem={({ item: comment }) =>
 <Review
   key={comment.commentId}
   comment={comment}
  />
 }
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
onEndReached={() => {
if (stationComments.length >= 28) {
  nextPage();
}
}}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
/>


No, it's not the issue. The ScrollView is not letting the FlatList do it's expected behavior.
